# How do I convert dates into ISO-8601 DateTime format in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, iso8601

I have the dataframe below (using python/pandas) and wish to convert the

```
q_string          q_visits  q_date
red               1790  02/10/2012 00:00
blue              364   02/10/2012 00:00
current           280   02/10/2012 00:00
molecular         259   02/10/2012 00:00
cell              201   02/10/2012 00:00
```

How can I convert the 'q_date' field into SO-8601 DateTime format (yyyy-MM- ddTHH:mm:ssZ)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the pandas datetools parser to parse the date and then format it using the standard python [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) function.

```
>>> df['q_date'].apply(
        lambda x: pd.datetools.parse(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
0    20120210T00:0000Z
1    20120210T00:0000Z
2    20120210T00:0000Z
3    20120210T00:0000Z
4    20120210T00:0000Z
Name: q_date, dtype: object
```

Comment: viktor this leaves it as object dtype so not that useful, better to use to_datetime

Comment: @Jeff I agree, it's just that the OP asked for a string, and the method I wrote was slightly faster than `pd.to_datetime(df['q_date']).apply(lambda x: x.strftime(...))` so I chose that one.

Comment: I think the `%` symbol after `M` should not be there. For me, using pandas v 1.2.4, the formatting string that worked was `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`

Answer (score 29):

I would use `pd.to_datetime` and the `.dt accessor`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['q_date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

See also [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 2):

use [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for pandas datetime format and use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#:%7E:text=date.-,strftime,-(format)) to convert to required format.

```py
currentDate = pd.to_datetime(df['q_date'])
convertDate = currentDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

or
use [isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat:%7E:text=date.-,isoformat,-()%C2%B6) to convert to ISO format.

```
convertDate = currentDate.isoformat()
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your `q_date` column into a `datetime64[ns]` Series, then `map` over the column with a custom format string

```
In [178]: df = df.convert_objects(convert_dates='coerce')

In [179]: df
Out[179]:
    q_string  q_visits              q_date
0        red      1790 2012-02-10 00:00:00
1       blue       364 2012-02-10 00:00:00
2    current       280 2012-02-10 00:00:00
3  molecular       259 2012-02-10 00:00:00
4       cell       201 2012-02-10 00:00:00

In [180]: df['iso_q_date'] = df.q_date.map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%y%m%dT%H:%M%SZ'))

In [181]: df
Out[181]:
    q_string  q_visits              q_date       iso_q_date
0        red      1790 2012-02-10 00:00:00  120210T00:0000Z
1       blue       364 2012-02-10 00:00:00  120210T00:0000Z
2    current       280 2012-02-10 00:00:00  120210T00:0000Z
3  molecular       259 2012-02-10 00:00:00  120210T00:0000Z
4       cell       201 2012-02-10 00:00:00  120210T00:0000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

To retain the time as well rather than just the date, use [**`pd.Timestamp.isoformat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.isoformat.html):

```py
df.q_date = df.q_date.pipe(pd.to_datetime).apply(pd.Timestamp.isoformat) + 'Z'
```

FYI, the `timespec` argument allows to specify additional terms of the time to include.