# What is the fastest they to convert string to DateTime (python)?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I've got a dataframe with **id** and **date** columns, date is a *string*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, '2020-03-26T15:37:19.765000Z'], [1, '2019-03-25T15:37:18Z'], [2, '2020-03-26T15:37:19.765000Z']], columns = ['id', 'date'])
```

I must convert date into DateTime for further working. I could find only one solution, with for loop.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (len(df.loc[i, 'date']) != 27): 
       df.loc[i, 'date'] = df.date[i].replace('Z', '.000000Z')

for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'date'] = datetime.strptime(str(df.date[i]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

It works as I need, but if df is large, it's unacceptably slow.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618288/how-do-i-convert-dates-into-iso-8601-datetime-format-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are using `pandas` so you can easily do this by using `to_datetime()` method:-

```
df['date']=pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: This will end you up with a TimeStamp type. If you wish to end up with a datetime type, just add a ".to_pydatetime()" suffix to Anurag answer.