# Convert pandas column with object type to date ISO 8601 format

Tags: python, pandas, date, iso8601

I have dataframe as below:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'User':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                     'Timestamp':['2021-12-09T23:00:00Z','2021-12-09T07:00:00Z','2021-12-09T15:00:00Z','2021-12-08T23:00:00Z','2021-12-09T11:00:00Z','2021-12-09T11:00:00Z'],
                     'Qty':[10, -10, 10, 30, 5, -5]})
```

I tried to use this solution [How do I convert dates into ISO-8601 DateTime format in a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618288/how-do-i-convert-dates-into-iso-8601-datetime-format-in-a-pandas-dataframe) to convert my Timestamp column to ISO 8601 format but it is not working:

```
df_test['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df_test['Timestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

My df_test['Timestamp'] still appear as object column instead of datetime. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def toiso(dt):
    d=datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    return d.isoformat()

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'User':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                     'Timestamp':['2021-12-09T23:00:00Z','2021-12-09T07:00:00Z','2021-12-09T15:00:00Z','2021-12-08T23:00:00Z','2021-12-09T11:00:00Z','2021-12-09T11:00:00Z'],
                     'Qty':[10, -10, 10, 30, 5, -5]})

df_test['Timestamp']=df_test['Timestamp'].apply(toiso)
'''
  User            Timestamp  Qty
0    a  2021-12-09T23:00:00   10
1    a  2021-12-09T07:00:00  -10
2    a  2021-12-09T15:00:00   10
3    b  2021-12-08T23:00:00   30
4    b  2021-12-09T11:00:00    5
5    b  2021-12-09T11:00:00   -5
'''
```

You must call function `apply` for dataframe and replace column to new value

Comment: I tried using your method and my Timestamp column still appear as Object instead of Datetime.