# Get UTC 'T' and 'Z' to show in DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc, iso8601

Importing a dataframe in one datetime format, feeding into API service that requires dates in this UTC format (notice the `T` and `Z`):

```
2023-07-26T11:04:23.893Z
```

Noteworthy is this will be converted into `JSON` so the final answer can result in a string. But would be much cleaner solution if the native `Pandas` time handling can do it.

On individual dates, not in a `DataFrame`, I've done it in this manner:

```
due_date_end = datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=+3)
due_date_end = due_date_end.isoformat('T') + 'Z'
```

When I try using the `.isoformat()` method on a `df` column I get an exception.

I've also tried the following:

Parsing dates when reading the file

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_test_file.csv',parse_dates=['job_due_date'])
```

Converting using related answers I've seen on SO:

```
df['due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(end_user_df['job_due_date']).dt.tz_localize('UTC')
```

And another variant based off of SO answers:

```
end_user_df['due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(end_user_df['job_due_date']).dt.tz_localize('UTC') 
end_user_df['due_date'] = end_user_df['due_date'].to_string().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
```

What should I try next?

Comment: as soon as you convert string to datetime (pd.to_datetime, parse_dates), you have a datetime data type, not a string. the datetime data type has no "format". only datetime in string representation has; so if you want T and Z to "show up", you have to convert to string, e.g. with `.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")` (notice that there is no % before the Z).

Comment: @FObersteiner, I get the following exception:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\d.kelly\Desktop\Python\PLEX_API_Test\plex_api_take_3.py", line 16, in <module>
    end_user_df['due_date'] = end_user_df['job_due_date'].to_string().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: if `end_user_df['due_date']` is a datetime column, use the `dt` accessor like `end_user_df['job_due_date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")` to get a string type column

Comment: @FObersteiner - Worked! TY - post as answer so I can mark as such for future SO searchers?

Comment: there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18618288/10197418), although I think what's still missing is how to get a certain precision in the fractional seconds (e.g. 2023-07-26T11:04:23.893Z vs. 2023-07-26T11:04:23.893111Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you'd want to convert datetime represented as string to datetime data type for working with the data. To generate an output (string) with a certain format, you'd use the `strftime` method of the `dt` namespace. Note that for `strftime`, you have to use a literal 'Z' to indicate UTC (not `%Z`).

Complementing an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61959823/10197418) to a similar question, here's an example how you can obtain different precisions of fractional seconds in the ISO format output.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2023-07-26T11:04:23.893001Z"]})

# for working with the data, convert to datetime data type
df["date_dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

print(df.dtypes)
# date                    object
# date_dt    datetime64[ns, UTC]
# dtype: object

# microsecond precision fractional seconds: just use %f
print(df["date_dt"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"))
# 0    2023-07-26T11:04:23.893001Z
# Name: date_dt, dtype: object

# millisecond precision fractional seconds: truncate output and add 'Z'
print(df["date_dt"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").str[:-3] + "Z")
# 0    2023-07-26T11:04:23.893Z
# Name: date_dt, dtype: object

# no fractional seconds at all: no %f
print(df["date_dt"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
# 0    2023-07-26T11:04:23Z
# Name: date_dt, dtype: object
```