# How do I convert ISO dates in a column with mixed date types in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas in Jupyter. I have a df, temperature_df, that includes >1 million rows each representing one measurement of a patients temperature. There is a temp_datetime column that includes two forms of date time mixed between rows. The two forms are "2019-01-24 23:02:00+00:00" and "6/27/2018  5:12:00 AM". The data this was pulled from used ISO 8601(I believe) format inadvertently, as I have manually checked and the date/times are correct in US central standard time, not UTC. I am trying to convert these dates in to the second form to get rid of ISO 8601 form and leave the dates and times exactly as they are. How can I do this?

example:

|  | temp_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-06-27 05:12:00 |
| 500000 | 2019-01-24 23:02:00+00:00 |

What I want:

|  | temp_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-06-27 05:12:00 |
| 500000 | 2019-01-24 23:02:00 |

Comment: what type is the column currently? and are they all `+00:00`? time is especially pernicious to coerce because of things like DST, so I'd recommend storing the times in something like `datetime64[ns]` and representing them in your desired format if all possible, even if it's wasteful

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618288/how-do-i-convert-dates-into-iso-8601-datetime-format-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: possibly a duplicate, but presumably the issue is that it's not a straightforward conversion because the times will be in UTC (due to their offset), while the times are _supposed_ to be in CDT

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to string and trim at the end:

```
df.temp_datetime.apply(lambda t: pd.Timestamp(str(t)[:16]))
```